# Derivative of $U: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider the function $U(x,y(x))$

I want to compute $\partial_x U(x,y(x))$

Therfore I get: $$\partial_x U(x,y(x)) + \partial_x U(x,y(x)) \cdot \partial_x y(x)$$

Can anybody tell how I can get to the + sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We set $g(x):=(x,y(x))$ and $V(x):= U(g(x))= U(x,y(x)).$

By the chain rule we obtain:

$$ V'(x)=U'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x),$$

where $\cdot$ denotes the inner product on $ \mathbb R^2.$

Hence

$$V'(x)=(U_x(x,y(x)), U_y(x,y(x)) \cdot (1, y'(x))= U_x(x,y(x))+U_y(x,y(x))y'(x).$$

Comment: OOOps, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

If $\ f(u,v)$ is a function where $\ u,v$ are functions of $\ x$ only, then $\ f$ is a function of $\ x$ only.
Then by chain rule, we have $\ \dfrac{df}{dx}= \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u}\dfrac{du}{dx}+ \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}\dfrac{dv}{dx}$